# Print only certain characters from array using map

Tags: javascript

I've below array and I want to print only first names from below array. I'm using split method. I'm wondering how we can do it using map?

```
var arr = ["firstA lastB", "firstC lastD", "firstE lastF"]

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i].split(' ')[0]);
}
```

Comment: `map` should only be used if you want to create a new array of just the first names. Otherwise, you should use `forEach`.

Comment: There is no need to use `map` here, a simple `forEach` can print the first name. using `map` and then `foreach` to print result will end up with 2 loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()` to return new array with modified items:

```js
var arr = ["firstA lastB", "firstC lastD", "firstE lastF"]

var arrRes = arr.map((item)=>item.split(' ')[0]);

console.log(arrRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var arr = ["firstA lastB", "firstC lastD", "firstE lastF"];
arr.map(name => name.split(" ")[0]).forEach(fname => console.log(fname));
```

Comment: You can simplify this even more with:

`arr.forEach(name => console.log(name.split(" ")[0]);`

Comment: @ACVM I know, the OP was asking about `map`, that is why I did it like this.